# How to get a list of measure names in AWS timestream?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-timestream

I want to get the list of measures in a timestream table, ie. the result of this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT measure_name FROM <db_name>.<table_name>
```

The problem with this query is that it scans the entire db, which is expensive.

I wonder if there's a better way of getting this list, especially because the AWS console has an option to show the measures ("Show measures" in menu of the table). [Screenshot of "Show measures" action in AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpknY.png).

I tried to find a specialized action to do this in the [API doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/API_Operations.html), but couldn't find anything. This left me to wonder if the AWS console runs the above (expensive) query everytime I look at the measures. Does it?

Side note: I need to run this from a python app / through boto3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use a "SHOW" statement.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/supported-sql-constructs.SHOW.html

```
SHOW MEASURES FROM database.table [LIKE pattern]
```